# How to get response data from a async khttp request in Kotlin

Tags: android, rest, api, http, kotlin

I am able to store the access token but now for example i wish to make a Toast message that says "user loggen in as [username]" but i get the error that this task is on a worker thread so i need to to this in the main thread. But i do not know how to get the data from my async request into the main thread and eventually do an explicit Intent to a new Activity while also passing the user's info and access token.

I already have a web application for the project that I'm working on and now i wish to make a companion app that will use my web applications REST api to get and post data. The web application is a Laravel application that uses Passport for handling logins. I'm new to android development but I was able to post my login data from my android app to the Laravel application and get a valid response meaning that the email and password match so I get the user's info and a access token.

```
inputSubmit.setOnClickListener { _ ->
            val email = inputEmail.text.toString()
            val password = inputPassword.text.toString()
            val address = prefrence.getValueString("API_ADDRESS") + "/login"
            val payload = mapOf("email" to email, "password" to password)
            var response : String
            var loginParsed : Login?
            khttp.async.post(address, headers=mapOf("Accept" to "application/json"), data = payload, timeout = 10.0, onResponse = {
                println("Status code: $statusCode")
                //println("Response text: $text")
                response = text
                loginParsed = Klaxon().parse<Login>(response) //Works
                prefrence.save("API_KEY", loginParsed?.access_token.toString()) //Works
                println("Logged in user: " + loginParsed?.user_name.toString()) //Works
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Korisnik: " + loginParsed?.user_name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }, onError = {
                println("ERROR MESSAGE: $message") //Works
            })
            //println("Username: " + loginParsed) // ! Variable 'loginParsed' must be intialized
        }
```

What i want is to be able to access the data outside of the khttp.async.post and pass in onto the new Activity and make a Toast message. When i try to make the Toast message i get the following error:

```
I/System.out: ERROR MESSAGE: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: You shouldn't had to get the error while showing toast as you are calling it on onResponse which runs in main thread only.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma And yet I am :/

Comment: Seems like onResponse is getting called in other than main thread, you must need to update the UI from main thread.

    `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Korisnik: " + loginParsed?.user_name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           // Launch desired activity from here, you can pass the required data in bundle
        }
    });`

Comment: Well okay sure that is a solution but what i really want to do is be able to access the parsed data outside of the khttp.async.post like im trying to do in  println("Username: " + loginParsed)

Comment: The reason is `loginParsed` getting initialized asynchronously mean that onclick listener block getting executed before that.